# How to set choice field values in Symfony2?

Tags: php, forms, symfony

Whats the best way to set a collection of key/values pairs (obtained from MySQL) as a choice field 'choices' inside a controller?
I think about something similar to :

```
 $form = $this->createForm(new AddNews(), $news);
 $newsList = $this->getDoctrine()
             ->getRepository('BakaMainBundle:News')->getAllNews();

 $titlesList = ...($newsList); // some fuction that extract title=>id 
                               // array from news object collection

 $form->get('newsList')->setData($titlesList);
```

where the AddNews() form looks like :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add(...)
            ->add(...)
            ->add('accept' , 'submit')
            ->add('newsList', 'choice', array
            (
                'mapped' => false,
                'required' => true
            ));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like below (assuming Symfony >= 2.7).  See [docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html) for field options:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add(...)
            ->add(...)
            ->add('accept' , 'submit')
            ->add('newsList', 'entity', array
            (
                'class' => ''BakaMainBundle:News'',
                'choice_label' => 'title',
                'mapped' => false,
                'required' => true
            ));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could get your "news" directly from your formType file, using your repository, like that:

```
    private function getNews(){    
    $newsList = $this->getDoctrine()
                 ->getRepository('BakaMainBundle:News')->getAllNews();

     $titlesList = ...($newsList); // some fuction that extract title=>id 
                                   // array from news object collection
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add(...)
            ->add(...)
            ->add('accept' , 'submit')
            ->add('newsList', 'choice', array
            (
                'mapped' => false,
                'required' => true,
                'choices' => $this->getNews()
            ));
    }
```